# Why can't the Quaternion Group definition be satisfied by a pair of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions, group-presentation

There is a quaternion group definition which states
$$Q_8 = \langle a, b \mid a^4 = 1, a^2 = b^2, ba = a^{-1}b\rangle$$
where $1$ is the identity element. This is suppose to produce eight distinct elements, but I believe I've found a way to do it with four.

Let $a = ([0], [1])$ and $b = ([1], [0])$, where $[0], [1] \in \mathbb{Z}_2$, and let the group operation be addition of the elements of the pairs,
$$([w], [x])([y], [z]) = ([w + y], [x + z]).$$
In this case, $1 = ([0], [0]) \neq a \neq b$, $(a^2)^2 = a^4 = 1$, $a^2 = 1 = b^2$, and $ba = ab = a^{-1}b$. Every condition is satisfied.

You could also think of this as two reflections in $D_4$, a square. Two perpendicular reflections $r_1$ and $r_2$ would satisfy all the same properties.

The definition of a quaternion is supposed to produce a more complicated set of elements than this, but I can't figure out why four elements don't cut it. What am I missing about generators or the definition to cause my interpretation to be so different from what was intended?

Comment: The notation $\langle a,b | \text{constraints} \rangle$ is supposed to represent the most *general* group satisfying the constraints, not the most simple one.

Comment: By the way, this notation does not necessarily require that $a \ne b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because$$\langle a,b\mid a^4=1,a^2=b^2,ba=a^{-1}b\rangle$$is the *largest* group spanned by two elements $a$ and $b$ such that those relations hold. If your computations are correct, then your group is a quotient of $Q_8$.

Comment: For the OP, it might be useful to note that the precise definition of the group generated by a presentation is to take the free group on $a, b,$ and quotient by the normal subgroup generated by the words $a^4, a^2b^{-2}, bab^{-1}a$ corresponding to the relations.

Comment: @MichaelBarz: in particular if you have $x^n=1$ that means that $x$ is supposed to have order $n$, unless the other relations impose a smaller order on $x$ (which is not the case here).

Comment: Unfortunately my text book doesn't use the term "free group," so that part might be precarious depending on the reader. If that term does get thrown in maybe add the definition. Other than that I never want to get in the way of improving answers.

Comment: @REsmond Are you saying that you have a textbook that gives a formal definition of a group presentation without using the concept of free groups? I would be interested to know what book that is and what is the definition precisely.

Comment: Yes. Just searched for "free", and I still found nothing. The Text Book is Abstract Algebra, An Inquiry-Based Approach by Hodge, K. Jonathan et al. There should be pdf's online that you can find. I don't believe there's any 2nd edition.

Comment: Note that the book starts on the Integer Axioms, and *ends* with groups. It's possible they selectively omitted some jargon when talking about groups, as it's just intended to be an introduction. They also never mention "words" either. That's my best guess.

Comment: @REsmond: I don't see any PDFs online. This book is under copyright from Chapman and Hall. Try looking of the definition of group presentation, or "von Dyck's Theorem" (which gives the universal property of group presentations).

Comment: No Von Dyck's Theorem. I'm starting to think this isn't the best textbook for group theory. Here's the only definition of Group *Generators*: "A subset S of a group G generates G if every element in G can be written as a finite product of the elements of S." They then give no formal definition of a Group Presentation, other than some examples, and the entire section on Generators and Group Presentations only took one page. I think I can say with confidence that this particular exercise problem should not have been in this book, given how much time was spent on the subject.

Comment: I did find a PDF online and I agree with your (R Esmond's) assessment. The definition given does not make it clear that a group presentation is intended to denote the most general group with the given generators that satisfies the given relations. It misleadingly suggests that if one of the relations is $R^4 = 1$, then $R$ has order $4$, which is false e.g., if you have the relations $R^4 = 1$ and $R^6 = 1$, then the order of $R$ must actually be $1$ or $2$.